# What do you get from lighthouse puzzle?

Tags: candy-box-2

I made it to this part, but it seems hard and there are tutorials for it, but I want to know what the reward is before I do it.

Answer (score 2):

You get:

> The P Stone, which is one of the four stones needed at the top of the castle in order to get the key to open the candy box.

Answer (score 0):

You get the P stone which is used to complete the game and open the candy box .At the end all the stone spell PLAY.